# Linux driver compatability

Tags: linux, drivers

How do I install extra linux drivers on an unsupported machine?

Edit: I used the package manager.

Comment: What do you mean by *extra* drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah,  age has nothing to do with Linux support. If there are no "drivers" on the official website,  then there aren't anywhere.